# A polynomial is less than an exponential function. Prove an inequality.

Tags: calculus, functions

If $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$$ is a polynomial
with $$|f(x)|\leq\left|e^ \left(x-1\right) -1\right|$$ for all $x\geq 0.$

Prove that $$|a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n|\leq 1.$$

I've recognized that the expression to be proven is derivative of the polynomial, but I'm completely thrown off by the modulus and I have absolutely no idea of how to do anything with the given information. I have plotted it graphically but modulus is throwing me off.

Comment: Actually, MathJax is easy - just have a look at the 
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The expression is the derivative of the polynomial at $x=1,$ not just the derivative of the polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Thomas, that's what I meant to convey. Also, thanks a lot for the edit. I'll learn mathjax for the next time I post.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904915/prove-that-a-12a-2-cdots-na-n-le-1-when-px-satisfies-this-condition).

Comment: Thank you David Mitra!

Comment: Can someone explain why my questions might be getting downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality in your hypotheses implies $f(1)=0$, then you have
$$
\left| \dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\right| = \left|\dfrac{f(x)}{x-1}\right| \leq \dfrac{|e^{{x-1}}-1|}{|x-1|},
$$
now let $x\to 1$ to conclude, since the right hand side is $|\left.\frac{d}{dx}\right|_{x=1} e^{x-1}|.$

Answer (score 0):

The assumption implies that $f(1)=0$ and for $h\in (0,1)$,
$$\frac {|f(1+h)-f(1)|}{h} =\frac {|f(1+h)|}{h} \le \frac{e^h-1}{h} \,.$$
Now take a limit as $h \downarrow 0$ to get
$|f'(1)| \le 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated the power of the exponent from x to x - 1. Maybe you want to adjust your answer.

Comment: The answer was already adjusted, take a careful look. $h=x-1$

Comment: Alright! Thank you!